# PHP mysqli prepared insert statement fails

Tags: php, insert, mysqli, prepared-statement

Here is the code.  $fieldNamesA and $fieldValsA are created in a foreach loop from POST variables:

```
$fieldNamesS = implode(',',$fieldNamesA);
$fieldValsS = implode(',',$fieldValsA);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pw', 'db');
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO users (?) VALUES (?)');
if ($stmt === FALSE) {
    die ("Mysql Error: " . $mysqli->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $fieldNamesS,$fieldValsS);
$stmt->execute();
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
```

Here are error msgs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?) VALUES (?)' at line 1' in userreg.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 userreg.php(47): mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO use...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /userreg.php on line 47
```

I don't understand why it is complaining that there is something wrong with my insert statement.  If I hardcode the column/field names, I get an error that the number of columns does not match the number of values, which is not correct.  I var_dumped the variables just to make sure and they have the same number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use placeholders for the column names with PHP Mysqli.

Check out this answer which talks about a PHP class I wrote to extend the mysqli class.  It will save you some time and it also does all the automatic placeholder bindings.

[better_mysqli class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219214/how-to-bind-in-mysqli-dynamically/17219806#17219806)

Comment: I hardcoded the column names it I got an error stating that the number of values didn't match the columns, which I double checked and could not find anything wrong.

Comment: Are you making sure there is one placeholder for EACH column (see Chris Hanson's answer above)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the names of the fields on the left side of `VALUES` then you need one ? for each of the values:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some, columns) VALUES (?, ?)
```

EDIT

You cannot have placeholders in the column list. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
>   (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column
>   in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>
> However, they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column
>   names), in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a
>   SELECT statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator
>   such as the = equal sign...

Comment: Ah, yea that was it.  So, just to have closure on this, you can't use a placeholder for column names?